# Framerate in command line usage of Compressor

Tags: terminal, command-line, compressor

I use Apple compressor from the command line to generate video clips from sequences of images. Here

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/compressor/cpsr9be73312/mac

it looks like the command line command allows for control of the framerate of the output movie, but I can't get things to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you refering to `<file>[?frameRate=<frame rate>|?audio=<file>|?frameRate=<frame rate>\&audio=<file>]`?

Comment: @nohillside Yes, exactly

Comment: I read this as `filename.suffix?framerate=25`. What exactly have you tried already?

Comment: @nohillside The input is a directory containing the images. So I tried ... `path_to_directory/?frameRate=25` as well as `path_to_directory/ ?frameRate=25`. Both do not work.

Answer (score 2):

So

```
Compressor -jobpath file:///path_to_png_directory?frameRate=60
```

does the trick.